# Ctrl+p causing bash to temporarily hang when in vi insert mode over ssh

Tags: macos, bash, vim, ssh

I recently switched to using vi mode (`set :o vi`) in my bash terminal. In the past, I've always used `ctrl+p` to look through previous commands, but for some reason after switching to vi mode bash hangs for about 20 seconds or so when I press `ctrl+p` in insert mode.

Note, this only happens over ssh. Locally it just inserts `^P`.

Does anyone know why this is happening, or how I can hack it to remove the `ctrl+p` shortcut from OS X Terminal (I'm happy with using `ESC, k, k,...`)?

Thanks

Comment: What is the ^P shortcut in Terminal? Which version?

Comment: Well, `ctrl+p` generally works for `up` in OS X, as they use a subset of the emacs bindings. I'm using OS X version 10.6.8. The issue seems to be with how the key combination is sent over ssh, since it behaves as expected locally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In insert mode, <kbd>^P</kbd> is bound to `menu-complete-backward`, so it’s running through all of bash-completion, which takes a while. If you want to cycle through the command history, you need to leave insert mode and use <kbd>k</kbd> and <kbd>j</kbd>. You could also bind <kbd>^P</kbd> to `previous-history`.

In the OS X version of bash (which uses BSD libedit instead of GNU readline), <kbd>^P</kbd> in insert mode doesn’t do anything.

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks Josh. I didn't realize that you could change bindings within the bash vi mode. How do you do this?